# I just proved weak convergence implies strong convergence, which can't be true!

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f_{n}$ converge weakly to $f$ in $L^2$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle f_{n},g\rangle=\langle f,g \rangle$ for all $g \in L^2$. Hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle f_{n}-f,g\rangle =0$ for all $g \in L^2$ in particular for $g=f_{n}-f$. Therefore $\langle f_{n}-f,f_{n}-f\rangle =0$ for all $n$ and hence $\int \mid f_{n}-f\mid ^{2}  \rightarrow 0$. But this is strong convergence in $L^2$ and I cant see what is wrong with the argument. Can someone point this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You went from $\langle f_n-f,g\rangle\to 0$ for each $g\in L^2$ to $\langle f_n-f,f_n-f\rangle\to 0$.  That is incorrect because $f_n-f$ is not a single element of $L^2$, but rather is changing to a different vector each time you change $n$.

For example, if $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal sequence, then $e_n\to 0$ weakly, which means for all $g\in L^2$, $\langle e_n-0,g\rangle=\langle e_n,g\rangle\to 0$ (a consequence of Bessel's inequality). On the other hand, $\langle e_n,e_n\rangle =1$ for all $n$.  It would be incorrect to take $g=e_n$, because it is not a fixed vector, independent of $n$.

I am not sure if you intended to write "Therefore $\langle f_{n}-f,f_{n}-f\rangle =0$ for all $n$," or if you meant to include a limit there.  If there is a limit, the "for all $n$" doesn't make sense.  If there is no limit (or even if there is), the equality is not justified.

Comment: well I tought since it holds for any element the vadility of being zero is true of any element $f_{n}-f$ aswell. But since it not a "simple equailty" but a limit it means that it only holds for the limit and not every element in the sequnece.
I see how  I was a little bit to creative, thanks!